# On Windows 7, when user1 logs in, user2's skype account signs in, how can this be prevented?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, skype

user2's skype account is set to autoconnect when user2 logs in.

However when user2 is logged off and user1 logs in, user2's skype also logs in. This is obviously undesired behavior. It's on Win7 x64.

Comment: Are you saying that when you log in with a certain user, a totally unrelated user is automatically signed in?

Comment: Yes, however I am still checking this, it is possible this occurs merely by windows starting up.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon User2 accidentally signed into Skype while User1 was logged into Windows. As you'd expect, Skype remembered this sign-in against User1's Windows account.

The fix is easy. Log into Windows as User1. Once Skype loads up and auto-signs-in as User2, sign out of Skype and sign in as User1. Problem fixed.

Comment: Thanks, however, user1 skype is set to auto-startup but not auto-login, so when user1 does login he sees a login screen, regardless of whether user2 is signed in.

Comment: Additionally, user2 is showing up as online even though they are not signed on anywhere (and this reflects across different platforms, both the app and PC).